# Is "constant theme" a canonical name of a math term? what is it?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

I am learning this [MIT course](https://youtu.be/Pw9N_mI1X5w?t=644).

The lecturer is saying

> we've broken up S into rank 1 pieces. That's like a constant theme.

S is a matrix that the lecturer is eigendecomposing.

In this context, is "constant theme" a canonical name of a math term? what is it?

Comment: Well, it sounds informal.  Like saying "you'll see, we do this sort of thing a lot."

Comment: ^ That is *definitely* what is meant by the term "constant theme".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a mathematical term.  A *theme* is "an idea that recurs in or pervades a work of art or literature" and what the lecturer is saying is this idea of splitting things up into rank 1 pieces is something that will come up over and over again throughout the course.

There are several things that can be thought of as 'themes' in mathematics:

- adding and subtracting the same term ("adding 0") in order to simplify an expression
- multiplying by a term and its inverse ("multiplying by 1") in order to simplify an expression
- use of a basis in finite dimensions to generalise ideas to a whole space/subspace
- taking a quotient by a map in order to create a space (or group or ring) which has a desired property

etc.  Identifying the themes for a course can be helpful in getting a good overview of the material.